# Sum of all numbers retrieved from firebase ionic 3

Tags: typescript, firebase, rxjs, ionic3

I am trying to find a solution to add up all the item's price that are retrieved from Firebase itself but somehow I cant figure out how to do it.. can anyone help me with it? Much appreciated!

Here is my firebase data: [Firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xGKE.jpg)

**Here is my typescript file**

```
export class CashierorderPage {

  orderItemRef$: FirebaseListObservable<any>

  constructor(

    public navCtrl: NavController, 

    public navParams: NavParams,

    private database: AngularFireDatabase,) 
    {
        this.orderItemRef$ = this.database.list('orders')
    }

}
```

Comment: What does represent an items price? If its `orderTotal` I think you made the mistake of saving the currency and the number under the same node.

Comment: i actually want to add up all the orderTotal prices

Comment: How are you planning to do that when it has that weird currency? You could technically use some string methods to extract that but that feels like a hack. Would saving the currency separately be a possible option to you?

Comment: yeap its possible, actually i just need to sum up the total amount from all of the tables but i am not sure how to do it...

Comment: How about this? Assuming all items returning from orders are in an array `this.database.list('orders').map( res => res.reduce((a,b) => (+ a.orderTotal) +  ( + b.orderTotal) ) )`

Comment: Okey! Will try it! Thanks!